# How can we check maximum HDD and SSD storage support

Tags: kubuntu, hard-drive, ssd, storage

I am using `Kubuntu 20.04` and in this laptop there are two storage slots. One is SSD and another is for HDD.
This laptop comes with 512GB SDD and an empty HDD slot to extend storage.
Currently, I want to buy a new internal HDD to put it in empty HDD slot.
But I don't know how much GB or TB of storage can support my empty slot.

Please help me if it is possible through terminal.

Comment: Hi That is a question you need to ask the maker of the laptop.

Comment: Depends on the controller (SATA?). I doubt the limits conflict with anything you would put into a laptop.

Comment: @David I already asked to customer care but they were unable to tell maximum capicity.

Comment: If the company that makes the laptop does not know who would?

Comment: @David My [laptop](https://www.flipkart.com/asus-tuf-gaming-f15-core-i5-10th-gen-8-gb-512-gb-ssd-windows-10-home-4-graphics-nvidia-geforce-gtx-1650-144-hz-fx506lh-hn258t-laptop/p/itm834e03127f443?pid=COMGFVWMDZPGK4WR&lid=LSTCOMGFVWMDZPGK4WRWRM8ES&marketplace=FLIPKART&q=asus+gaming+laptop&store=6bo%2Fb5g&srno=s_1_11&otracker=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_8_na_na_na&otracker1=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_8_na_na_na&fm=search-autosuggest&iid=5041adf7-9b8d-403b-91fb-b80e7975c6c4.COMGFVWMDZPGK4WR.SEARCH&ppt=hp&ppn=homepage&ssid=5lm677ba7k0000001646914162541&qH=7ec1d95853ab0b71)

Comment: If possible, please try to investigate !

Comment: *an empty HDD slot* Don't you mean a 2.5" SATA drive slot? It doesn't have to be an HDD as there are SATA SSDs with the same form factor. Any currently sold capacity of HDD or SSD should work, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubuntu20.04 comes with ext4, and by citing
https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/maximum-file-size

```
The ext4 file system can support volumes 
with sizes up to 1 Exabyte (EB) (1,000 Terabytes = 1018 Bytes) 
and files with sizes up to 16 Terabytes (TB).
```

However, I fully agree with @David. If you need to understand what disks are supported by your hardware, go to the product page on the manufacturer and check there.